# RSA Asymmetric Key Generation at User Signup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, expo

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I would like to create an end-to-end system using React Native (Expo) and Node.js. I have tried various libraries for asymmetric (RSA) key generation, but none seem to work.

How can I proceed to generate a pair of public and private keys?

Here is the setup:

import { RSA } from 'react-native-rsa-native';

```
export default function App() {
     useEffect(() => {
         (async() => {
             let message = "my secret message";

             RSA.generateKeys(4096) // set key size
                 .then(keys => {
                     console.log('4096 private:', keys.private); // the private key
                     console.log('4096 public:', keys.public); // the public key
                 });
         })()
     },[]);

}
```

Here's what brings you back:

```
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateKeys' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'generateKeys' of null
```

Comment: @ruakh, I used chatGPT, because I didn't know how to clearly expose the problem 

Comment: I didn't see a problem description anywhere...

Comment: @ruakh I made it shorter and simpler, hoping that it would be understandable.

Comment: `I have tried various libraries for asymmetric (RSA) key generation` which ones, we don't want to suggest the same - `but none seem to work.` what issues do you have? Perhaps your *code* is wrong

Comment: I used react-native-rsa-native and react-native-rsa

Comment: and react-native-crypto does not offer RSA encryption

Comment: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's your end goal here? Why are you trying to generate RSA keys? Also you mentioned you tried with react-native-rsa-native and react-native-rsa libraries, what errors do you face and post the code you have for this. if you provide more info as such, other people might be able to help you.

Comment: @v1shva I need it to set up an end-to-end encryption system

Comment: I added the code, is it more understandable?